# Why does my python program reset while looping?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a nested `for loop` that exports combinations to a text file.
However, around the 480th count value, the nested for loop will reset (as well as the count variable).

```
x1values = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
x2values = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
y2values = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
x3values = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55]
y3values = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 55]
x4values = [100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70]
count = 0
for x1 in x1values:
    for x2 in x2values:
        for y2 in y2values:
            for x3 in x3values:
                for y3 in y3values:
                    for x4 in x4values:
                        if x2 >= x1 and x4 >= x3 and y2 <= x2 and y3 >= x3:
                            with open('PS_COMBOS.txt', 'a') as f:
                                count += 1
                                f.write(str(y2) + ':' + str(x3) + ':' +
                                        str(y3) + ':' + str(x4) + ' COUNT: ' + str(count) + '\n')
```

[Showing counter and loop resetting in the txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w15ll.png)

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need 6 nested loops: `for x1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4 in product(x1values, x2values, y2values, x3values, y3values, x4values): ...` (where `product` is imported from the standard `itertools` module.)

Comment: You don't need to initialize or increment `count` yourself: `for count, ... in enumerate(product(...)):`

Comment: And finally, you don't need to repeated open` the same file for every `write` statement: `with open(...) as f: for count, ... in enumerate(product): f.write(...)`.

Comment: All that said, there's no reason to wait until you are in the innermost loop to check, for example,  if `x2 >= x1`; you can do that before you start iterating over `y2values` at all.

Comment: And finally, I don't believe the code you show here would produce the output shown in the linked image.